# How to position a button to the bottom right side of an image?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have an ion slide box and it displays images.  I want to add a button, `ion-plus-round`, to the bottom right side of the image.  I don't want to add it to the bottom right of the slider, but rather to the bottom right side of the `img` only.

```
<ion-slide-box class="item-slide-box">      
      <ion-slide ng-repeat="image in vm.item.images" ng-cloak >
        <img ng-src="{{image}}">

      </ion-slide>     
    </ion-slide-box>
   <a class="button icon ion-plus-round myButton"></a>
```

I have done the following but I am wondering how I can get the button to be `float: right` inside of the img:

```
.slider {
height: 60vh;
background-color: #76838f;
position: relative;
}

.slider-slide {
 color: #000;
 background-color: #76838f;
 height: 100%;
} 

.slider .slider-slide .img-ng {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.slider .slider-pager {
    bottom: 45px;
}

 .myButton {
    position: absolute;    
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

codepan: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPYBpR

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle or code snippet? Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: hey please i am not sure how to do that.  can i post a screenshot of the output

Comment: You'll have to learn at some point so I'll explain how to use it :) Go to http://www.jsfiddle.net and type in your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code. By default, the javascript code runs when the page loads but if you want to create your own event listener, you can change the setting by going to the gear icon in the javascript panel and changing it to "no wrap in head". Click run as you type your code to experiment and when you are done, click "save". Then share a link to your question for everyone to see :)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPYBpR  sorry i just saw your message i went ahead and found an ionic code pend and just put my codes there

Comment: i am trying to get the button to be located bottom right of the img :(

Comment: can someone please help me

Comment: I tried with pure CSS and nothing worked. I'm not familiar with ion, but I added `ion` tags to your question. Hopefully that brings in people familiar with your code.

Comment: I tried as well and wasn't able to figure it out. The styles aren't able to be overridden and whatever framework you are using seems to create new HTML elements that will mess up the environment for adding the desired behavior. You will need to go without the framework (sadly) unless the framework offers another option for your desired behavior.

Comment: I can try to write your desired result without the framework if you would like :)

Comment: sure.  i am interested to know how it would work.  thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just edited you code, you can try this in code pane and check whether it is fulling your requirements.

Html code:

```
<ion-slide-box class="item-slide-box">      
          <ion-slide ng-cloak class="content">     
            <img class="img-ng" ng-src="http://geomorph.sourceforge.net/fourier/Bouboule256.jpg">
            <a class="button icon ion-plus-round myButton"></a>     
          </ion-slide>     
        </ion-slide-box>
```

add some css line like:

```
 .content{    
    position:relative;
}

.content a{

    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    right:5px;
}
```

Note:remove ".myButton"  css from css and place button after the image source as shown in code,Hope this would exactly what you want.

For example if you really want the button exactly on the image just follow the example code and you can implement this code in your code.

HTML:

```
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/182x121"/> 
    <a href="#">Can be BUTTON/LINK</a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .main{    
    width: 182px; /*328 co je 1/3 - 20margin left*/
    height: 121px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-right:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.content a {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    right:5px;
    background:blue;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

above code will can help you give button on the image.

Comment: thanks Ajit.  that is a lot close to what I was aiming for!  thank you for this